# Let $A$ be a $n\times n$ matrix such that $a_{ij}=ij$,find the eigenvalues of the matrix $A$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a $n\times n$ matrix such that $a_{ij}=ij$.

I want to find the eigenvalues of the matrix $A$.

Efforts: $n=2$, I found that eigenvalues are equal to $0,5$.

For $n=3$, I found eigenvalues are equal to $0,0,14$.
For $n=4$ I found eigenvalues are equal to $0,0,0,30$.

For $n=5$ I found eigenvalues are equal to $0,0,0,0,0,55$.

It looks like there is a pattern here. Eigenvalues of $n\times n$ matrix seems to be $\sum_{i=1}^n i^2, \underbrace{0,0,0,..0}_{n-1\text{ times}}$.

But how can I prove it? I mean whether there are some beautiful arguments that makes things easy, and ideas clear.

Thanks for reading and helping out.

Comment: If you can prove that $0$ is an eigenvalue with multiplicity $n-1$ (see Arthur’s answer), then you get the remaining eigenvalue "for free:" the sum of the eigenvalues is equal to the the trace.

Comment: @amd Thanks a lot. The problem becomes quite simpler now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off, all columns are multiples of one another, so the matrix has rank $1$ and therefore eigenvalue $0$ with multiplicity $n-1$.

For the final eigenvalue, some experimenting gives a strong hint: For $n = 2$, we get that the eigenvector of the non-zero eigenvalue is [$(1, 2)^T$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=eig%7B%7B1,+2%7D,%7B2,+4%7D%7D), and for $n = 3$ we get [$(1, 2, 3)^T$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=eig%7B%7B1,+2,+3%7D,%7B2,+4,+6%7D,%7B3,+6,+9%7D%7D). This is a quite suspicious pattern. Let's check whether that holds in general:

Let $A$ be our $n\times n$ matrix, and $v$ be the vector where the $i$th entry is $i$. We get
$$
Av = \begin{bmatrix}1\cdot 1 + 2\cdot 2 + \cdots + n\cdot n\\
2\cdot 1 + 4\cdot 2 + \cdots + 2n\cdot n\\
\vdots\\
n\cdot 1 + 2n\cdot 2 + \cdots + n^2\cdot n\end{bmatrix} = (1^2+2^2+\cdots + n^2)v
$$

Comment: Thanks Arthur. I get the idea. This is what I wanted to learn. :)

Comment: The other (nonzero) eigenvalue is simply equal to the trace.

Answer (score 3):

$\{x:\sum jx_j=0\}$ is an $n-1$ dimensional subspace. Any basis for this gives you $n-1$ independent eigen vectors with eigen value $0$ and the only other eigen value is $1+2^{2}+3^{2}+\cdots +n^{2}$ as seen easily from definition of eigen values and eigen vectors.

Use the fact that $\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n}  ijx_j=\lambda x_i$ implies that $x$ is a multiple of $(1,2,\cdots,n)$