# Eigenvalues of an $n\times n$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I got a question about the eigenvalues of an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ whose entries are $a_{ij}=ij$, $i,j={1,2,...,n}$. I have to answer what the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of this matrix are.

I have found out that $\lambda_1=Tr(A)$ for all $n$ and the rest are $0$ through inspection (using R). But I have no clue where to begin in my proof since there is no formula for the characteristic polynomial for $n\geq4$. I also found out that the eigenvectors are all orthogonal to each other.

#EDIT#
Found the answer its posted below

Comment: **Hint**: $A=vv^T$ where $v=(1,\dots,n)^T$

Comment: Thanks I will try that in a moment

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Let $A$ be a $n\times n$ matrix such that $a_{ij}=ij$,find the eigenvalues of the matrix $A$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3157941/let-a-be-a-n-times-n-matrix-such-that-a-ij-ij-find-the-eigenvalues-of-th)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint :** All the rows of your matrix are proportional, so the rank of the matrix is $1$.

So you have only two eigenvalues, which are $0$ and $$\mathrm{Tr}(A) = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$

Comment: Thanks I've gotten the proof for $Tr(A)=\lambda_1$. Using $gemu(\lambda) = nullity(A-\lambda I_n)$ and $gemu(\lambda )\leq almu(\lambda$). Got me a step in the right direction. I am now solving the second part about the eigenvectors.

Comment: Do you agree that the matrix has rank $1$ ? If so, then it's kernel has dimension $n-1$, therefore you have only two eigenvalues, which are $0$, and another one. You finally have to prove (trigonalizing if you want), that the other eigenvalue is the trace of the matrix.

Comment: Yes thanks for the extra clarification that is what I did in the proof. I've also found a general formula for the eigenvectors for $E_0=ker(A-0I_n)$. Only part left is the eigenvector for $E_{Tr(A)}$

Comment: I got the answer! Thanks for your help used your comment and the one from Matthew Holder to get the eigenvector $E_{Tr(A)}. Cant post the full answer yet since its for a graded homework assignment and i'll get in trouble for plagiarism. Will post it on sunday.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be a $n \times n$ matrix whose elements are given by $a_{ij}=ij$. Find its eigenvalues and its eigenvectors.

We will be using these 3 equations to prove that $\lambda_1 = Tr(A)$ and that $\lambda_2, \cdots,\lambda_n = 0$
\begin{equation}
Tr(A) = \lambda_1 + \lambda_2 + \cdots + \lambda_n.
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
Det(A) = \lambda_1\lambda_2 \cdots \lambda_n.
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
gemu(\lambda) \leq almu(\lambda)
\end{equation}
With $gemu(\lambda)$ giving the geometric multiplicity and $almu(\lambda)$ giving the algebraic multiplicity. Matrix $A$ is a symmetric matrix and since all its rows are proportional to each other $rank(A)= 1$. Since $rank(A) \ne n$ we know that $Det(A)=0$. Using equation (4) we can derive that at least one of the eigenvalues is equal to $0$. We now look at the geometric multiplicity of $0$. $$gemu(0) = nullity(A-0I_n) = n- rank(A) = n-1 $$
Using equation (5) we get $n-1\leq almu(0)$ and since there is at least one nonzero eigenvalue because $Tr(A)\ne0$ we know that $almu(0)=n-1$.\
That leaves us with one eigenvalue left and looking at equation (3) the only possible candidate is the  trace itself.

To find the eigenvectors of matrix $A$ we start by looking at $E_0= ker(A-0I_n) = ker(A)$. $rref(A)$ is a matrix with a top row vector of $(1,\cdots,n)$ and the rest filled with 0's.\
Case n=4:\
$$\left(\begin{array}{llll}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right) \begin{array}{l}
x_{1}=-2 s-3 t-4 u \\
x_{2}=s \\
x_{3}=t \\
x_{4}=u
\end{array}$$
$$ker(A)=span\left(\left[\begin{array}{c}
-2 \\
1 \\
0 \\
0
\end{array}\right],\left[\begin{array}{c}
-3 \\
0 \\
1 \\
0
\end{array}\right],\left[\begin{array}{c}
-4 \\
0 \\
0 \\
1
\end{array}\right]\right)$$
\
It can be seen that for any n the set of $n-1$ of $n \times 1$ eigenvectors $\{v_1,\cdots,v_k\}$  for $\lambda=0$ $\vec{v}_k$ can be given in this way:
\begin{equation}
\vec{v}_k=\left[\begin{array}{c}
-(k+1) \\
1 \\
0 \\
\vdots \\
0
\end{array}\right]
\end{equation}
Where the 1 is on the $(k+1)$ position of the vector. Since $gemu(0)=n-1$ and a $n \times n$ matrix has a maximum of $n$ eigenvectors, the only eigenvector left to find is the eigenvector with eigenvalue  $\lambda=Tr(A)$.\
We are going to make use of the fact that if $\vec{v}= (1,\cdots,n)^T$ then $A=vv^T$ and $Tr(A)=v^Tv$. Now to find the last eigenvector.\
$E_{Tr(A)}=ker(A-Tr(A)I_n)$ we need to find vector(s) $\vec{x}$ such that $(A-Tr(A)I_n)\vec{x} = \vec{0}$. Now for $\vec{x}$ choose $\vec{v}$ and substitute $A=vv^T$ and $Tr(A)=v^Tv$ . We get:

$$(vv^T-v^Tv)v = \vec{0}$$
$$vv^Tv-v^Tvv = \vec{0}$$ Due to associative property $(AB)x=A(Bx)$ we get
$$v(v^Tv)-(v^Tv)v = \vec{0}$$ which gives $ Tr(A)v - Tr(A)v = \vec{0}$. This proves that for any $n$ the eigenvector associated with eigenvalue $Tr(A)$ is $\vec{v}= (1,\cdots,n)^T$.\
To conclude for any $n \times n$ matrix $A$ whose elements are given by $a_{ij}=ij$ the eigenvalues are  $\lambda_1 = Tr(A)$ and  $\lambda_2, \cdots,\lambda_n = 0$.
The associated eigenvectors are $E_{Tr(A)}= (1,\cdots,n)^T$ and $E_0 = span(v_1,\cdots,v_k)$ whose vectors are given by equation (6).